Проблема с подключением к MS SQL Server из внешней сети
Вводные данные :

SQL Server 12.0.6329 (права read only)
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio на серверной машине
Сервер находится в локальной сети за роутером
Роутер с белым IP
Клиент во внешней сети
Через VNC доступ к серверной машине есть из внешней сети
Порт SQL нестандартный - 15000
Сервер является помимо прочего сервером определённого софта. Клиентской частью этого софта можно пользоваться извне, прописав белый IP роутера. (порт, видимо, зашит внутри).

На роутере настроена переадресация порта на серверную машину.
Прав на изменение чего-либо в SQL Server нет, т.к. софт сторонний и тех. поддержка со скрипом выдала доступы к SQL.
Изначально реализовывал работу с SQL с удалённой машины из внешней сети через pyodbc, однако столкнулся с вязанкой ошибок и решил отладить соединение, для начала, через файл UDL.
Для этого установил Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server.
В настройках SQL Server Authentication --> Login, Pass
Шифрование --> Optional
ُ
Настроил файл на сервере - успешное соединение и с ИМЯ\АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА_БД и с tcp: <локальный IP>.
Настроил файл на компьютере из локальной сети - успешное соединение с tcp: <локальный IP>, port
Настроил файл на компьютере из локальной сети - успешное соединение с tcp: <белый IP роутера>, port
Настроил файл на клиенте из внешней сети - ошибка с tcp: <белый IP роутера>, port :
"Не удалось выполнить вход для имени ввода 'login_name' из-за выполнения триггера." (17892)
Был проверен фаервол на серверной машине - порт исключен из блок листа во всех видах.
Test-NetConnection <белый IP роутера> -Port ##### --> соединение устанавливает
Ping <белый IP роутера> --> превышен интервал
Через python пробовал другие библиотеки и ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server с тем же результатом.
Подскажите, в каком направлении ещё копать, учитывая отсутствие возможности вносить правки в сервер, но при этом работоспособность его из локальной сети и из внешней сети через свой клиент софта.

Ошибка "Не удалось выполнить вход для имени ввода 'login_name' из-за выполнения триггера.(17892)" говорит о том, что на сервере есть logon-триггер, который вероятно запрещает соединение по какому-либо критерию (например, имя хоста или IP адрес). Если есть права гляньте, что там за триггеры SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers.

Запрос выполнен успешно, но пустая таблица на выходе. Поэтому, даже не знаю. Слаб в SQL Серверах.

Если результат пустой, то, вероятнее всего, что недостаточно прав для того, чтобы видеть триггеры уровня сервера. Видимо нужно теребить поддержку, чтобы они посмотрели почему на сервере logon-триггер не даёт подсоединиться извне. Может настроят исключение (для определённого логина, например).

Сейчас изучать буду вопрос с подменой айпи после проброса через роутер, дабы база видела локальный IP. Может это сработает.

В результате, как и предполагалось, ограничения были на стороне сервера, который не принимал запросы не из локального пула адресов. Соответственно, решением стало :

Изменение политики сервера.
Запросы из локального пула.
Изменение запроса, дабы сервер видел запрос, как из локального пула.

